# Sitecore Rocks 2.1, where are "renderings and placeholders"

Tags: sitecore-rocks

I had setup the display of some custom facet info about a year ago.   At the time I followed: https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/04/19/extending-sitecore-experience-profile-speak-app/

Now, I need to tweak two fields that are being rendered.

For the life of me, I can not find how to get to the "Renderings and Placeholders" screen in Sitecore Rocks 2.1.

Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to edit a tab in `core > sitecore > client > Applications > Experience Profile > Contact > PageSettings > Tabs`  ctrl+Enter doesn't do anything and 'Tasks' only offers: `Set Insert Options`... and `Sort Template Fields`

Comment: Go to `/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Contact` and hit `ctrl + enter`. That will bring up contact's presentation details. I think that's what you're looking for. There should be a tab control: https://www.screencast.com/t/89ZognMG7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Teeknow 's moral support, I discovered that...

1. my Sitecore Rocks connection was somehow configured for "Good Old Web Service"
2. changing to Hard Rock Service resulted in some nasty error.
3. by performing an update of the server components I was able to change to "Hard Rock Service"

Now, I have the missing menu items back.  *phew*

Answer (score 3):

Select the item and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>.

This shortcut is shown in the context menu as well.

[image: Sitecore rocks]

**UPDATE:**

To edit tab layout located here `core > sitecore > client > Applications > Experience Profile > Contact > PageSettings > Tabs` you need to select the individual tab item beneath that 'Tabs' Item.

[image: Edit Tab Layout]